# how to debug type conversion errors in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm a javascript noob and trying to learn angular.

I have some simple angularJS code like this:

```
<div ng-controller="todoController">
    <span> temp = {{tempVal()}} </span>
</div>
```

**the bug is easy enough**,   tempVal is a string, not a method.

***My problem (and question) is, how do I discover this fact when debugging?***

I am using Chrome and have the Batarang extension installed, however all I get is a cryptic stack trace:

```
TypeError: string is not a function
at http://localhost:6202/lib/angular-1.0.4/angular.js:6213:13
at Object.$interpolate.fn (http://localhost:6202/lib/angular-1.0.4/angular.js:4829:22)
at Object.watchExpression (http://localhost:6202/AddSomeControl/index.html:416:29)
at Object.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:6202/lib/angular-1.0.4/angular.js:7783:38)
at Object.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:6202/lib/angular-1.0.4/angular.js:7991:24)
at Object.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (http://localhost:6202/AddSomeControl/index.html:500:30)
at http://localhost:6202/lib/angular-1.0.4/angular.js:932:13
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:6202/lib/angular-1.0.4/angular.js:2813:25)
at bootstrap (http://localhost:6202/lib/angular-1.0.4/angular.js:930:12)
at angularInit (http://localhost:6202/lib/angular-1.0.4/angular.js:906:5) angular.js:5601
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out how, using these tools in a complex application, I could discover that the error is somewhere around that **tempVal()** line.

i tried setting a break point right when the error is being logged and looked up the callstack, and see a caught exception in $get.Scope.$digest that can maybe tell me the parent scope id (this.target.$id), along with what "watcher" (this.length) it is that crashed, and the previous completed html element (this.value)....    is that the best way?  what a pain :(

Comment: Watch the video on http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html. It explains very well how to debug Angular, at least I am able to fix now all stuff despite being still a JavaScript beginner.

Comment: yeah i watched that,  it's good for general debugging, but unfortunatly it doesn't handle situations like what I'm describing.

basically, angular doesn't have good debug error reporting  (Batarang isn't for error reporting, it's for template/state inspection)

Comment: I would investigate the function tempVal on the console (after selecting the scope as shown in the video). But maybe I can help if you post the code of the function here.

Comment: i know what the error is, just i don't see any easy way to troubleshoot this if I didn't realize that tempVal() was a string, not a method.

here's a link to the bug i reported on the angularjs tracker, it has the repo source,  though really it comes down to the framework being very complex and difficult to debug.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1974

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the answer, unfortunatly, is that you can't debug this class of errors.

well, you can, it's called "learn the angular compiler/vm and debug it"

there's no dev-user friendly wrapping of these types of usage errors.

Comment: Just for easy reference so that people can see angular team response and perhaps help : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1974

Comment: thanks for mentioning the issue, sorry i didn't post-back a link myself!